# Internet connectivity drops upon installation

Tags: dual-boot, internet

I'm dual booting Ubuntu Mate with Windows xp (just to keep a few things) it installs just fine but as soon as I restart it after it won't connect to the Internet either by WiFi or by ethernet. Ive tried having xp release the ip with no avail. The WiFi won't turn on and there is no option to turn it on. I've read a bit about it requiring an extra driver but it's odd that it works while I stalling but not after.

When I shut it down I get a screen plastered in writing and a blinking underscore and then the machine doesn't shutdown.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.`

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nvram                  16384  0
msr                    16384  0
snd_hda_codec_idt      53248  1
dell_laptop            24576  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
video                  24576  1 dell_laptop
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
snd_hda_intel          32768  3
ssb                    57344  1
snd_hda_codec         118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
mii                    16384  0
snd_hda_core           57344  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
wl                   6152192  1
kvm_amd                57344  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   454656  1 kvm_amd
snd_pcm                90112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69632  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
k8temp                 16384  0
edac_core              49152  0
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
i2c_piix4              20480  0
cfg80211              483328  1 wl
shpchp                 32768  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
pata_acpi              16384  0
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                    98304  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
radeon               1466368  5
psmouse               114688  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                    86016  1 radeon
sdhci_pci              20480  0
drm_kms_helper        114688  1 radeon
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
drm                   303104  8 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
pata_atiixp            16384  0
ahci                   32768  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ati_agp                16384  0
```

`dmesg` runs over the character count. 
Sorry for the formatting.

It uses broadcom hardware.
`grep`s don't return any information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of the commands `lsmod`, `dmesg | grep Ethernet`, `dmesg | grep Wireless` and `iwconfig`. Also include some Ethernet/WLan related hardware information.

Comment: Not letting me edit; `iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.`

It uses broadcom hardware.
`grep`s don't return any information.

Comment: That's really bad. Seems like the correct Wireless and Ethernet modules weren't loaded at all. Please give your network hardware specs.

Comment: Broadcom 440x 10/10p integral controller. Dell wireless 1390 WLAN mini-card

Comment: Please take a look at the following question. The hardware seems to be the same. Try to follow the steps given in the answers, they may help you.

askubuntu.com/questions/443721/no-network-connection-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: I haven't got a chance to try it and am now away from the computer but just wanted to thank you for looking into it. I'll post back once I get to the computer again.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10?

I have also faced same problem and install Ubuntu

Try to use LTS version.The Rolling Release version has a few bugs

Comment: Recommending the usage of another version is not an acceptable answer unless the used version has already reached its End-of-Life.

Comment: Its 15.10, which would you suggest? I did have lxle on it and it worked just fine.

Comment: I suggest you to use ubuntu 14.04